# R max of multiple categories

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, categories

I've got data somewhat like this (of course with many more rows):

```
Age     Work Zone     SomeNumber
26      1          2.61
32      4          8.42
41      2          9.71
45      2          4.14
64      3          6.04
56      1          5.28
37      4          7.93
```

I want to get the maximum SomeNumber for each zone at or below each age. SomeNumber increases with age, so I expect that the highest SomeNumber in Zone 2 by an under-32-y/o is by a guy who's age 31, but it could in fact be a guy age 27.

To do this I've written a nested for loop:

```
for(i in zonelist){
  temp = data[data$zone==i,]
  for(j in 1:max(data$age)){
    temp.lessequal=c(temp.lessequal,max((temp[temp$Age<=j,])$SomeNumber))
  }
  #plot temp.lessequal or save it at this point
}
```

which of course is tremendously slow. How can I do this faster? I've looked at the order function to sort by two columns at once, but that doesn't let me take the max of each group.

Comment: @Sathish This question doesn't seem duplicate to me if I have understood it properly. May be I'm wrong.

Comment: My answer is an exact duplicate of one of the solutions in the link posted above

Answer (score 1):

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text='Age Work_Zone  SomeNumber
26      1          2.61
                   32      4          8.42
                   41      2          9.71
                   45      2          4.14
                   64      3          6.04
                   56      1          5.28
                   37      4          7.93', 
                   header = TRUE)
```

**Code:**

```
df2 <- with( df1, df1[ Age <= 32, ] )  # extract rows with Age <= 32
# get maximum of someNumber by aggregating with work_zone and then merging with df1 to combine the age column
merge(aggregate(SomeNumber ~ Work_Zone, data = df2, max), df2) 
#   Work_Zone SomeNumber Age
# 1         1       2.61  26
# 2         4       8.42  32
```

Comment: I don't think OP is hard-coding 32 anywhere but used it as example. He/she is looking for current row's *Age*.

Answer (score 0):

Using the library `data.table` you can select the rows which are less than required age, then output the `max(somenumber)` and their respective age for each Workzone ie group by workzone.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[Age<=32,.(max(SomeNumber),Age),by=Work_Zone]
   Work_Zone   V1 Age
1:         1 2.61  26
2:         4 8.42  32
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

It seems OP is looking for `max` value based on `<=` condition on a particular column (`Age`).

The use of `sqldf` comes very handy in such cases in order to explain the logic. One solution could be:

```
# Data 
df <- read.table(text = "Age     Work_Zone     SomeNumber
26      1          2.61
32      4          8.42
41      2          9.71
45      2          4.14
64      3          6.04
56      1          5.28
37      4          7.93", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

library(sqldf)
df3 <- sqldf("select df1.Work_Zone, df1.Age, max(df2.SomeNumber) from df df1 
       inner join df df2 on df1.Work_Zone = df2.Work_Zone 
       WHERE df2.Age <= df1.Age 
       GROUP BY df1.Work_Zone, df1.Age")

# Result:
#   Work_Zone Age max(df2.SomeNumber)
# 1         1  26                2.61
# 2         1  56                5.28
# 3         2  41                9.71
# 4         2  45                9.71
# 5         3  64                6.04
# 6         4  32                8.42
# 7         4  37                8.42
```